# JS Приобразование даты к формату d F Y

Tags: javascript, дата, datetime

Подскажите как на JS преобразовать дату формата `YYYY-MM-dd` в `d F Y`

Мне с `2023-01-27` надо получить `27 Jan 2023` Продовал воспользоватся вот [этой документацией](https://itchief.ru/javascript/date).

```js
let currDate = '2023-01-27';
let d = new Date(currDate);
let normDate = d.getDate() + " " + d.getMonth() + " " + d.getFullYear();

console.log(normDate)
```

Но что-то пока не то выходит. Может JS умеет уже без сторонних библиотек такое ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Может JS умеет уже без сторонних библиотек такое ?

Ещё как умеет!

```js
const input = '2023-01-27';
const string = new Date(input).toLocaleString(`en-UK`, { day: `numeric`, month: `short`, year: `numeric` });
console.log(string);
```

---

И вашим способом можно

```js
let currDate = '2023-01-27';
let d = new Date(currDate);
let normDate = `${d.getDate()} ${d.toLocaleString(`en`, {month: `short`})} ${d.getFullYear()}`;
console.log(normDate)
```

Comment: спасибо, может ещё объясните, почему в моем тестовом примере `d.getMonth() ` ничего не возвращает?

Comment: @BlackStar1991 `getMonth()` возвращяет число от 0 до 11 в зависимости от месяца. Так тоже можно реализовать, но встроенные методы удобнее.

Comment: спасибо, за объяснение